# Sending C# Workers over different Virtual Machines

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, networking

My question is very simple, but the answer might not be.
I have thousands of workers performing the same task, and I would like them to be executed in a parallel fashion on many remote virtual machines (Cloud or Network)

Here is the idea :

```
class ThreadManager
{
    public void main()
    {
      for (int i = 0; i<300; i++)
      {
        myWorker wk;
        if (i < 100)
            wk = new myWorker(IP_Computer_1);
        else if (i < 200)
            wk = new myWorker(IP_Computer_2);
        else 
            wk = new myWorker(IP_Computer_3);

        wk.RunWorkerAsync();
      }
    }

    internal class myWorker :: BackgroundWorker
    {     
       public string IP_Computer;
       {...}//constructor

       protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
       {              
          WriteToDatabaseTable("BAZINGA !  Greetings from computer " + Dns.GetHostName());
          //SQL server DB is hosted on a publicly accessible domain
          base.OnDoWork(e);
       }
    }
}
```

Of course, this is pseudo code, you get the idea : Assigning threads/workers to different computers/VM's over the network (not only multi-cores)
What basic/simplest options do I have ?
I am open to ANY light and efficent solution (I do not want to go into complex scheduling/app workflow  reengineering, etc... let's keep it as plain as it is, please)

NB : *This is NOT an innocent question. I am aware of all the fuss about grid/cloud computing, HPC , Amazon web services, Azure etc... I spent a lot of time reading around and trying stuff, and my opinion is that there are a lot of (money) business going out there. Sometimes it's good to go back to basics and ask simple questions to see if we really need an overly sophisticated/complicated/invasive/expensive solution to solve basic issues (we are not a Fortune 500 with a giant network, but just a small research company with specific/atomic computing needs)*

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your negatives against the cloud... _overly sophisticated/complicated/invasive/expensive_

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get started with .NET grid computing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249198/how-to-get-started-with-net-grid-computing)

Comment: @Forgotten Semicolon : I saw that one and was wondering if after one year there was more chances to have more comprehensive answers to such a fundamental issue...

Comment: @Aaron : I've tried both Amazon EC2 and Azure (hands-on). As of now, I found no way to cluster EC2 instances to perform a computing process using windows (HPC instances are Linux only) and for Azure, we had storing issues as we had to perform a high rate I/O operations, not to mention that application (re)deployment was a pain, as it is not as seamless as a VM. Anyway, I have nothing against clouding, I just want to find if there is a basic, simple, way and step-by-step way to perform clustering/grid over cloud or other VM's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to model your "DoWork" as a method on a WCF service. 
Use NetTCP bindings, and [load balance across multiple machines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730128.aspx). This is appropriate if the machines are stateless clones, and all state is maintained on the database.  In that case you shouldn't care about which machine services your request, and you shouldn't need to futz with IP addresses at the application level.

That provides no communication guarantees, no reliability or failover. For example, if the servicing machine "dies" during a request, the request would not be restarted on another machine.  This may be just fine for your needs.

If you want guaranteed delivery (aka fire-and-forget) and transaction durability, consider using the MSMQ Transport for your WCF Service. In this case the service machine dequeues transactionally, and the transaction commits only if the database update has been performed.

Comment: Thank you that was very insightful. I'll give this a try (I don't know how exactly, but I'll read the docs and try the API's out). As of reliability and failover, this is not a problem, I have a parallel cross check system and if some service failed I'll have it re-run in the next process pool.

Comment: I welcome and step-by-step guide or any useful available resource to help me start into that. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about [NGrid](http://ngrid.sourceforge.net/) an open source Grid computing. If you want to do it all by yourself you need quite a bit of coding to get fault tolerance baked into your custom solution. The most difficult is keeping failures local without impacting your whole system.

Comment: Ngrid has stopped being maintained for 3 Years, and I prefer to have user feedback beofre digging deeper into it. As of fault tolerance, it is not a problem my App handles that. If a worker fails, I have cross checking to know it and run it again.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ngrid/: Last Update: 2009-08-05. Not looking overly alive :(

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of unanswered questions in your... well.... question.  Conceptually, this is a very simple task, however once you start getting some details it becomes more and more challenging.

As stated in your question I understand that you want to fire and forget tasks to distributed processors.  Meaning that each task is atomic and no return is necessary.  A way to do that is to create a listening server on the distributed nodes that your main node would then send messages containing the serialized work objects to execute.  The distributed nodes would then fire off a new thread (or worker process) to perform the processing.

Then the problem begins to scale up based on how much more functionality is involved.

Comment: From a conceptual and architectural point of view, this sounds sensible. From a programming perspective, there are various options and I do not know where to start

Comment: This might help.   http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amit_agrl/DistributedComputing11232005043409AM/DistributedComputing.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to understand is that you can certainly send data to other computers rather easily (ie. WCF) ... however, you can't easily send code/logic. So you can approach the issue in one of two ways:

- Have an "installation procedure" where you manually take the workers and distribute them to each computer that will participate in the exercise, then send them the pieces of data to process via WCF, or MSMQ, or any other number of remote communication techniques
- Have the master process be able to serialize a .net assembly, transmit it to each slave/worker process, and have that worker load the assembly into an application domain, then proceed with sending them the bits to work on.

Either way, you'll have to solve firstly the communication issue (do you push via something like WCF, or do you have the slaves pull from a Queue), etc.

Answer (score 0):

.NET has no easy built-in way to do this.  You probably want to make your workers serializable and send them to nodes through a message queue (perhaps using `System.Messaging` and MSMQ).

Comment: Yeah, No easy built-in way to do this, That was my guess... As of the Nodes stuff, if you could give me more details/resources about the front end to make it more concrete that woudl be great.

Comment: I don't agree; WCF makes it pretty durn easy.